# css transform 2 faced cube always rotate up

Tags: javascript, css

i'm trying flip this 2 faced cube so it looks like it is always rotating up.

here is what I have so far

demo 
https://jsfiddle.net/m5z0u6ct/2/

I increase the degrees by 90 degrees each time you click the button.
but at 270 degrees the cube rotates down.
1) How can I make it so the cube continually rotates up on each click?
2) How can I prevent the text from flipping after the 2nd click? (I'd like the text to always look right side up like it does on the first two clicks)

```
/* Container box to set the sides relative to */
    .cube {
        width: 30%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;

        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .33s;
        transition: transform .33s; /* Animate the transform properties */

        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d; /* <-NB */
    }

    /* The two faces of the cube */
    .flippety,.flop {
        background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
        border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);

        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
        height: 100px;
    }

    /* Position the faces */
    .flippety {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
        transform: translateZ(50px);
    }

    .flop {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
        transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
    }

    /* Rotate the cube */
    .cube:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(89deg);
        transform: rotateX(89deg); /* Text bleed at 90º */
    }
    .cuberotate {
            width: 30%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;

        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .33s;
        transition: transform .33s; /* Animate the transform properties */

        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
        transform: rotateX(90deg); /* Text bleed at 90º */
    }


    .cuberotateit {
            width: 30%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;

        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .33s;
        transition: transform .33s; /* Animate the transform properties */

        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(89deg);
        transform: rotateX(89deg); /* Text bleed at 90º */
    }



     var degrees=0;

    $("#btnflipflop").on('click', function (e) {

                    $("#questioncube").attr('class', "cuberotateit");


                    degrees = degrees + 90;


                    $('.cuberotateit').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateX(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                    $('.cuberotateit').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + degrees + 'deg)');




                });

     <div id="questioncube" class="cube">
            <div id="card1" class="flippety">
                <h1>Flippity</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="card2" class="flop">
                <h2>Flop</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: on third/forth click you see the backface you may hide with backface-visibility:hidden or use scale() also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working correctly. You only have two of the four faces so what you're seeing is the back side of the two faces for the 3rd and 4th iterations. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m5z0u6ct/3/) with `backface-visibility: hidden;` added.

### Update

You need to set `position: relative;` on the `.cube` and `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;` on each of the faces. If you disable the `transform` and `-webkit-transform` on each of the faces, you'll see how the default `position: static;` affects their layout.

Here's a demo of the updated (and cleaned) code:

```js
var degrees = 0;

$("#btnflipflop").on('click', function(e) {
  degrees += 90;

  $('#questioncube').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateX(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  $('#questioncube').css('transform', 'rotateX(' + degrees + 'deg)');
});
```

```css
/* Container box to set the sides relative to */
.cube {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .33s;
  transition: transform .33s;
  /* Animate the transform properties */
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* <-NB */
  position: relative;
}
.face1,
.face2,
.face3,
.face4 {
  background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.face1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
  transform: translateZ(50px);
}
.face2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.face3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(50px);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(50px);
}
.face4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateZ(50px);
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateZ(50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questioncube" class="cube">
  <div id="card1" class="face1">
    <h1>face1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="card2" class="face2">
    <h2>face2</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="card3" class="face3">
    <h1>face3</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="card4" class="face4">
    <h2>face4</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="btnflipflop" type="button" value="flipme" />
```

Comment: thanks but how do I add the 3rd and 4th faces to this code?

Comment: @user713813 add more faces to your DOM... follow the pattern that's there. you need more than `.flippety` and `.flop`

Comment: ok I followed the pattern and got this https://jsfiddle.net/m5z0u6ct/4/ but see how face3 is still giving me trouble?  I took out the backface hidden so you can see that it pops out and not like the others.